# Is there an @salesforce import or uiRecordApi service for custom settings in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, customsetting

I have an LWC that needs to use a value from a (hierarchy) custom settings object, when available.

I know I can write an Apex method and call it via a wire to address this, but I was hoping to find an [@salesforce import module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_salesforce_modules.html) or [uiRecordApi wire](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record) that would provide this ability in a more out-of-the-box manner.

It looks like writing my own Apex method is the only viable approach, which is a shame, but thought I'd float the question just in case someone found something I could use that the documentation doesn't cover properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been the case since aura days, unfortunately, there is no way in LWC/Aura to get Hierarchical CS.

I have raised this idea few years back which you can upvote:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4vkQAC

Comment: I raised [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015BDLQA2) too, but not two years back. Perhaps you could vote for mine as well :)

Comment: @PhilW upvoted. Hope this get's implemented next release